# mocked method not being invoked

Tags: java, mockito

I am using testng with Mockito and due to a restriction I cannot use PowerMock. When i try to run my test, for some reason the real method is called instead of the mock! I have added a wrapper class around the class which has static methods. I know from the documentation that Mockito does not support static methods. So, as a way over it, I have written a simple wrapper which just calls the static method in that class.

```
public class BatTrafficManagerStatsHelperTest {

    @Mock
    private MtsConfFactoryWrapper mtsConfFactoryWrapper = new MtsConfFactoryWrapper();

    private static final String EXPECTED_JSON_STR = "{"
            + "         \"duration\": 100,"
            + "         \"timestamp\": \"1970-01-01T00:00:00\","
            + "         \"cellMetrics\": {"
            + "           \"enb1_cell1\": {"
            + "             \"handoverAttempts\": 2,"
            + "             \"rrcConnectionAttempts\": 1"
            + "           }"
            + "         },"
            + "         \"trafficProfileMetrics\": {"
            + "           \"voipSpeech_2PDN\": {"
            + "             \"srMtSuccess\": 4,"
            + "             \"numberOfUEs\": 100,"
            + "             \"srMoSuccess\": 3,"
            + "             \"attachSuccess\": 5,"
            + "             \"rrcConnectionAttempts\": 1"
            + "           }"
            + "         },"
            + "         \"ueGroupMetrics\": {"
            + "           \"ueGroup1\": {"
            + "             \"handoverAttempts\": 2,"
            + "             \"numberOfUEs\": 100,"
            + "             \"rrcConnectionAttempts\": 1"
            + "           }"
            + "         }"
            + "       }";

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    /**
     * getBstmString()
     * Setup mock, tests getBstmString() and verify result
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetBtmString() throws Exception {
        final Date date = Mockito.mock(Date.class);
        Mockito.when(date.getTime()).thenReturn(0L);

        final Map<OptimizedRoute, List<StatsQueue>> ueStatsTrackerMock = getUeStatsTrackerMock();
        final Map<Enb, List<OptimizedCellStatsQueue>> cellStatsTrackerMock = getCellStatsTrackerMock();
        final MtsConfBuilder confBuilderMock = Mockito.mock(MtsConfBuilder.class);
        final Tracker trackerMock = Mockito.mock(Tracker.class);

        Mockito.when(mtsConfFactoryWrapper.getConfBuilderr()).thenReturn(confBuilderMock);
        Mockito.when(confBuilderMock.getTracker()).thenReturn(trackerMock);
        Mockito.when(trackerMock.getUeStatsTracker()).thenReturn(
                ueStatsTrackerMock);
        Mockito.when(trackerMock.getCellStatsTracker()).thenReturn(
                cellStatsTrackerMock);
        Mockito.when(trackerMock.getConfiguredTrafficProfiles())
                .thenReturn(
                        getFakeTrafficProfilesList());

        BatTrafficManagerStatsHelper btmStatsHelper = new BatTrafficManagerStatsHelper(date);
        String result = btmStatsHelper.getBtmString(TIME).replace("JsonDataForBatTrafficManagerRegex:", "");

        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        assertEquals(parser.parse(result), parser.parse(EXPECTED_JSON_STR));
    }

}
```

The orginal class under test looks like this

```
public class BatTrafficManagerStatsHelper {

    private final Date date;

    /*
     * Constants for BAT Traffic Manager log parsing
     */
    private static final ImmutableMap<String, String> AHL_STATS_CONSTANTS_TO_BTM_CONSTANTS = ImmutableMap.of(
            BatAeroflexHLStatsConstants.RRC_CONNECTION_REQUEST_ATTEMPTS, "rrcConnectionAttempts",
            BatAeroflexHLStatsConstants.HANDOVER_ATTEMPTS, "handoverAttempts",
            BatAeroflexHLStatsConstants.SERVICE_REQ_MO_SUCCESS, "srMoSuccess",
            BatAeroflexHLStatsConstants.SERVICE_REQ_MT_SUCCESS, "srMtSuccess",
            BatAeroflexHLStatsConstants.ATTACH_SUCCESS, "attachSuccess");
    private static final String NUMBER_OF_UES = "numberOfUEs";

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param date
     */
    public BatTrafficManagerStatsHelper(Date date) {
        this.date = new Date(date.getTime());
    }

    /**
     * Extracts log data and returns it in a format suited
     * for parsing in {@literal BAT Traffic Manager}.
     *
     * @param elapsedTime
     * @return log data for BAT Traffic Manager
     */
    public String getBtmString(long elapsedTime) {
        MtsConfFactoryWrapper mtsConfFactoryWrapper = new MtsConfFactoryWrapper();
        Map<OptimizedRoute, List<StatsQueue>> ueGroupTracker = mtsConfFactoryWrapper.getConfBuilderr().getTracker()
                .getUeStatsTracker();
        Map<Enb, List<OptimizedCellStatsQueue>> cellTracker = mtsConfFactoryWrapper.getConfBuilderr().getTracker()
                .getCellStatsTracker();

        BatTrafficManagerStatsHelperJson json = new BatTrafficManagerStatsHelperJsonBuilder()
                .setDuration(elapsedTime)
                .setTimestamp(getTimeStamp())
                .setCellMetrics(getCellMetrics(cellTracker))
                .setTrafficProfileMetrics(getTrafficProfileMetrics(ueGroupTracker))
                .setUeGroupMetrics(getUeGroupMetrics(ueGroupTracker))
                .build();

        return "JsonDataForBatTrafficManagerRegex:" + getJsonString(json);
    }

}

public class MtsConfFactoryWrapper  {
    public MtsConfFactoryWrapper() {}

    public MtsConfBuilder getConfBuilderr() {
        return MtsConfFactory.getConfBuilder();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your test class,

```
@Mock
private MtsConfFactoryWrapper mtsConfFactoryWrapper;
```

instead of

```
@Mock
private MtsConfFactoryWrapper mtsConfFactoryWrapper = new MtsConfFactoryWrapper();
```

You shouldn't assigned a new object to `mtsConfFactoryWrapper` variable. A mock object will be assigned to `mtsConfFactoryWrapper` variable when `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` get called.

In your method you are always creating a new object like below,

`MtsConfFactoryWrapper mtsConfFactoryWrapper = new MtsConfFactoryWrapper();`

So even you mocked the object in your test, when the method get called, it will again create a new object. Try to inject that to the class instead of creating a new instance inside your method.

Your class should look like this,

```
public class BatTrafficManagerStatsHelper {

    private MtsConfFactoryWrapper mtsConfFactoryWrapper;

    public BatTrafficManagerStatsHelper(MtsConfFactoryWrapper mtsConfFactoryWrapper) {
        this.mtsConfFactoryWrapper = mtsConfFactoryWrapper;
    }

    // other stuffs
}
```

In your test class when you create the object of `BatTrafficManagerStatsHelper`, pass your mock object to the constructor as below,

```
public class BatTrafficManagerStatsHelperTest {
    @Test
    public void testGetBtmString() throws Exception {
        //your code

        BatTrafficManagerStatsHelper btmStatsHelper = new BatTrafficManagerStatsHelper(passYourMockedObjectHere);
    }
}
```

Comment: i removed the initialization as you said, but still the same :(

Comment: So now here is what I have done with no luck. I moved the instantiation to the constructor

    public BatTrafficManagerStatsHelper(Date date) {
        this.date = new Date(date.getTime());
        this.mtsConfFactoryWrapper = new MtsConfFactoryWrapper();
    }

Also, removed the object creating from within the method. 

in the test class

    @-Mock
    private MtsConfFactoryWrapper mtsConfFactoryWrapper;
    final Date date = Mockito.mock(Date.class);
    @-InjectMocks
    BatTrafficManagerStatsHelper btmStatsHelper = new BatTrafficManagerStatsHelper(date);

Comment: I think you have misunderstood what I said. You need to inject the `MtsConfFactoryWrapper`. I have updated my answer again

Comment: @user1716304 - Please accept the answer so that the question gets closed.